# Slack API: How to send a scheduled private message to every member in the channel?

Tags: slack, slack-api, bolt

I want to send a weekly private message to all channel members.

I'm using currently using `app.event('app_home_opened')` to do such a thing. But I want the open rate to be higher, and that's why I want the bot to send the message automatically.

chat.scheduleMessage works perfectly but I have to pass a channel id as a parameter, meaning that only 1 person will receive the message.

How can I achieve what chat.scheduleMessage does, but for every single member?

Answer (score 2):

According to my search and knowledge I think with slackapi we can send message only one channel at a time..

But I think if you implement like this then you can send messages to multiple channel

Steps:
add all channel in one array and apply loop , then one by one channel id will pass and message will send to all channel. If you want to different channel messages to all channel then you can also add messages in channel array

Hope you got solution